# ¿Como puedo imprimir el numero de caracteres de una string sacada de una enumeracion?

Tags: java, enum

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente codigo

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

enum Perros
{
    Mastin, Terrier, Buulldog, Pekines, Caniche, Galgo;

    public int length() {
        return 0;
    }
}
public class PROG02_EJER6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String intro;
            int Charlong;
            Perros cont;
            Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Mastin",1);
            map.put("Terrier",2);
            map.put("Bulldog",3);
            map.put("Pekines",4);
            map.put("Caniche",5);
            map.put("Galgo",6);
            Perros var1, var2;
            var1 = Perros.Mastin;
            var2 = Perros.Terrier;
            System.out.println(var1.compareTo(var2));
            System.out.println("la posicion de la variable 1 es "+ var1.ordinal());
            System.out.println("la posicion de la variable 2 es "+ var2.ordinal());
            System.out.println((Perros.values().length));
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre de la raza de la que quieras saber informacion (Mastin, Terrier, Buulldog, Pekines, Caniche, Galgo)");
            intro = sc.next();
            if(map.containsKey(intro));
            map.get(intro);
            cont = Perros.valueOf(intro);
            Charlong = cont.length();
            System.out.println(Charlong);
                System.out.println("Esa raza se encuentra en la posicon "+map.get(intro)+ " Ademas ese elemento de la enumeracion contiene "+Charlong);
        }
    }
}
```

Me gustaria que en la parte del if:

```
System.out.println("Introduce el nombre de la raza de la que quieras saber informacion (Mastin, Terrier, Buulldog, Pekines, Caniche, Galgo)");
                intro = sc.next();
                if(map.containsKey(intro));
                map.get(intro);
                cont = Perros.valueOf(intro);
                Charlong = cont.length();
                System.out.println(Charlong);
                    System.out.println("Esa raza se encuentra en la posicon "+map.get(intro)+ " Ademas ese elemento de la enumeracion contiene "+Charlong);
```

Sacar tanto la posición dentro de la enumeración de el elemento escrito por teclado como la cantidad de caracteres que tiene ese elemeto de la enumeracion:

```
#Ejemplo: enum = hola, adios, chao
#Entrada escribe el elemento del que quieras saber la posicion en la enumeracion y el numero de caracteres que tiene: hola
#Salida Hola se encuentra en la posicion 1 y tiene 4 caracteres
```

He estado probando distintos comandos como podeis ver en el codigo pero no me acaba de salir ya que la salida de mi programa en la parte de la posicion me la da bien pero en la parte de el numero de caracteres por algun motivo que desconozco la variable que cuenta los caracteres es igual a 0
Muchas gracias de ante mano <3

Comment: Creo que necesitas entender primero cómo funciona la sentencia `if` y el uso de llaves (`{...}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te lo menciona Pablo, debes de cuidar la sintaxis de las condicionales en tu código si declaras un `if` o un `else` para obtener el numero de caracteres dependiendo de la raza ingresada,podes hacer uso del método [`name()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-convert-enum-to-string/)
el cual devuelve el nombre de la constante de enumeración tal como se declaró en su declaración de enumeración.

```
System.out.println("Introduce el nombre de la raza de la que quieras saber informacion (Mastin, Terrier, Buulldog, Pekines, Caniche, Galgo)");
    intro = sc.next();
    if(map.containsKey(intro)){
    cont = Perros.valueOf(intro);
    charlong=cont.name().length();
    System.out.println("Esa raza se encuentra en la posicon "+map.get(intro)+ " Ademas ese elemento de la enumeracion contiene "+charlong);
 }else{
System.out.println("Esa raza no se encuentra en ninguna posicion");
}
```